# What's the right transition equation of this problem?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

For every mouse, it takes two months for them to become mature after birth, then they are able to give birth to baby mouses. A mature mouse can give birth to 12 baby mouses every month. We have one mouse initially, and what's the total numebr of mouse after ten months?
My transition equation is F(n) = F(n-1) + 12 * F(n-2), but my classmate told me this is not right. So what's the right equation of this question?

Comment: Initially, F(0) = 1 initially one mouse, F(1) = 1 as after one month no mouse matured... but at F(2) is it going to be 1 or 13(if birth takes place just after maturation), please clarify...

Comment: Is your first mouse matured to give birth?

Comment: The first mouse need two months to become mature. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Your transition equation needs to be a matrix (3x3) so that given 3 states as a vector (newborn, 1m old, 2m+ old) gives you new vector of new states after 1m. Logic to build such matrix is similar as your reasoning.

```
new_state = matrix * current_state
```

EDIT:

matrix that we build represents 3 linear equations.

```
# abbreviations
ns = new state
nb = newborn
1m = 1 month old
2m = 2 mounts old or more
cs = current state
mXX = matrix index

# 3 scalar questions from matrix eqution ->
# ns = matrix * cs 
ns_nb = m00 * cs_nb + m01 * cs_1m + m02 * cs_2m
ns_1m = m10 * cs_nb + m11 * cs_1m + m12 * cs_2m
ns_2m = m20 * cs_nb + m21 * cs_1m + m22 * cs_2m
```

Now you need to figure out what m00 - m22 are based on your requrements

Comment: Could you help us in understanding by showing some states of a matrix, Please?

Answer (score 2):

Enlightened by answer by Luka above, I figure out these coefficients

> ns_nb = 12 * cs_2m + 12 * cs_1m
>
> ns_1m = cs_nb
>
> ns_2m = cs_2m + cs_1m

Comment: I am not sure 1st one is correct. From what I have read I would expect that newborn mouse can make 1st mouse 3months after it was born. That is one month after it was mature.

Comment: My understanding is that the new born mouse can only be brought by newly matured mouses and those elder ones. So by definition, cs_1m will be the newly matured ones and cs_2m stands for elder ones.

Comment: Oh sorry, new born mouse can make 1st mouse 2 months after it was born.

Answer (score 1):

From the posts of Luka Rahne and KningTG,

I think the python code below will work fine for the problem using dynamic programming:

```
# Initial Conditions
new_born = 1
one_month_old = 0 
mature_mouse = 0 

n = 10  # Month upto which we want to find
i = 1 

while(i<n):
    
    # Finding updated new value
    new_born_update = 12*(one_month_old+mature_mouse)
    one_month_old_update = new_born
    mature_mouse_update = one_month_old + mature_mouse

    # Updating values
    new_born,one_month_old,mature_mouse = new_born_update,one_month_old_update,mature_mouse_update
    
    i = i + 1
    
# Calculating the total number of mouses for month n
Total_mouses = new_born+one_month_old+mature_mouse

# Printing total number of mouses
print(Total_mouses)
```